# Error when deploying node.js app to heroku: "ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered"

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a node.js but the build fails with the following message when trying to build dependencies:

```
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        npm ERR! path /tmp/build_4e98ad92f183bbb8473f7c8cea6a64dc/node_modules/bootbot
remote:        npm ERR! code ELOOP
remote:        npm ERR! errno -40
remote:        npm ERR! syscall access
remote:        npm ERR! ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, access '/tmp/build_4e98ad92f183bbb8473f7c8cea6a64dc/node_modules/bootbot'
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-01-05T02_45_15_488Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
```

I believe this is happening because of one the dependencies I specified, which is a forked repo I'm hosting on GitHub, but I cross-checked and the syntax seems correct

```
"dependencies": {
    "_package_": "https://github.com/_username_/_repo_/tarball/master",
},
```